# D3 - how to label x Axis correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, d3.js

My goal is to label my x-axis with years from 1960 to 2080 in steps by 10. 
I have a .csv file which looks like this:

```
Land,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2060,2070,2080
Belgien,9128824,9660154,9855110,9947782,10239085,10839905,11824225,12885338,13918014,14758714,15400272,16027593,16614305
```

So far i got this result (see picture)

[Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bclq7.jpg)

I do not know how to label the x-axis correctly. Here is my code so far:

```
d3.csv("/Data/temp_eu_popul.csv", function(e, eu_popul) {
console.log(eu_popul);


var years = [1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2060,2070,2080];
    console.log(years);

var population = [];
  for(var i = 1960; i<=2080; i+= 10){
    population.push(parseFloat(eu_popul[0][i]));
  }
console.log(population);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(population))
  .range([250, -50]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,years.length])
  .range([100, 450]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
    svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(75,150)")
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,450)")
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .call(xAxis);

var circles = svg.selectAll("cirle").data(population).enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d,i){ return x(i); })
.attr("cy", function(d,i){ return 350-y(d); })
    .attr("r", 2);
});
```

I thougth the way to go is to change:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(years))
  .range([100, 450]);

var circles = svg.selectAll("cirle").data(population).enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx", years)
.attr("cy", function(d,i){ return 350-y(d); })
    .attr("r", 2);
});
```

Another thing is, that I created an extra array for the years. But I bet there is a better way to get around that. Because the years are already in the csv file. Can I somehow use them without creating an extra array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(years)) // or .domain(d3.extent(eu_popul[1]))
  .range([100, 450]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,450)")
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .call(xAxis); 

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(population).enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d,i){ return x(years[i]); })
.attr("cy", function(d,i){ return 350-y(d); })
    .attr("r", 2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your x axis scale can be thought of in your case as an ordinal scale, so you'll need to use

`x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(years).range([min, max])`

, where min and max are your own values for the x extent, which will map your exact years to pixel x values.

For the "cx" calls you should then use 
`.attr('cx', function(d) {return x(d)})`

or more concisely, 
`.attr('cx', x)`

which is d3 shorthand for the same thing.

You also have a spelling mistake in your `circles` variable, you've selected all "cirle"s!

Also, I think your csv data should ideally be in a vertical rather than horizontal format:

`Land, Belgien
 1960, 9128824`

etc.

and then you can access the properties `d.Land` and `d.Belgien` wherever you want the corresponding numbers to influence your markup, from within an anonymous `function(d,i){}` definition, and you can construct your years array for example by using

`var years = eu_popul.map(function(d) {return d.Land});`

Comment: hm, when I change the to code x = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(years).range([min, max]) I get an empty page. Changing range([min,max]) back to .range([100, 450]); I get an output, but it looks weird. Are min, max predefined in d3? So does my code know what min and max is?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said min and max should be replaced by your own values!

Comment: Edited now, see above

Comment: weird in what way? and no, max and min are not predefined in d3 - pretty much anything that d3 does know about (that isn't a regular javascript function) is prefixed/namespaced by d3, eg d3.scaleLinear, d3.select etc